# Uploading a file to Azure Blob Storage using VBA and MS XMLHTTP

Tags: vba, ms-access, azure, http-headers, blob

I've been trying to upload file to Azure storage using VBA in Microsoft Access but so far without success.

I have had a good search around and have found some code which looks promising but I can't get it to work. Seems like many others have been looking for a similar solution or help with working with Azure from VBA.

This is the code;

```
Private Function pvPostFile(sUrl As String, sFileName As String, Optional ByVal bAsync As Boolean) As String
Const STR_BOUNDARY  As String = "3fbd04f5-b1ed-4060-99b9-fca7ff59c113"
Dim nFile           As Integer
Dim baBuffer()      As Byte
Dim sPostData       As String

'--- read file
nFile = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Binary Access Read As nFile
If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
    ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
    Get nFile, , baBuffer
    sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
End If
Close nFile
'--- prepare body
sPostData = "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    sPostData & vbCrLf & _
    "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"
'--- post
With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", sUrl, bAsync
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & STR_BOUNDARY
    .Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)
    If Not bAsync Then
        pvPostFile = .ResponseText
    End If
End With
End Sub

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
    pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```

(Thanks to - https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/)

When I try this code using my azure storage URL in the form

```
https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/
```

and a filename (C:\Temp\Test.txt) I get the following error;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>UnsupportedHttpVerb</Code><Message>The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.
```

I suspect there's a problem in the header or post data rather than the VBA and this is not really my area.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe there are a few problems: 1) The URL should be `https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/file-name`. 2) All the requests to Azure Storage should be authenticated. I don't see you setting an `Authorization` header anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for comment - I will take a look into these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this post as I'm searching the same answer for uploading images to Azure Blob Storage. I took me 2 days to get the answer. And the code posted above did help me to partly solve the problem.

I would like to post my solution here in case anyone else is looking for the same answer.

Before you can use the code below, you need to get the Shared Access Signature (SAS) from your Azure portal (manage panel). You should be able to google the answers on this.

```
Public Sub UploadAfIle(sUrl As String, sFileName As String)
    Dim adoStream As Object
    Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    adoStream.Mode = 3          ' read write
    adoStream.Type = 1          ' adTypeBinary
    adoStream.Open
    adoStream.LoadFromFile (sFileName)
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        adoStream.Position = 0
        .Open "PUT", sUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "0" 'this is not a must
        .setRequestHeader "x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob"
        .Send adoStream.Read(adoStream.Size)
    End With
    Set adoStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

sURL is a URL looks like (I'm in China so the Host is different): https://myaccount.blob.core.chinacloudapi.cn/products/newimagename.jpg**?sv=2016-05-31&ss=bfpq&srt=dco&sp=rydlscup&se=2017-07-30T18:40:26Z&st=2017-07-28T10:40:26Z&spr=https&sig=mJgDyECayITp0ivVrD4Oug%2Bz%2chN7Wpo2nNtcn0pYRCU%4d**

The one bolded is the SAS token you generated from Azure.

Comment: Thanks for following up and posting this - I'll take a look.

Comment: I've managed to get this working - thanks again for posting it. 
Do you know the header type when working with an Azure file share instead of blob storage? The "x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob" generates an error when trying to upload to a fileshare

Comment: Good to know that this is working for you. I don't know the header type for Azure File Share. But I think "x-ms-blob-type" should be "x-ms-blob-content-type".

Answer (score 3):

Worth noting the format of the sUrl in SiliconXu's answer is made up of 3 parts, I didn't realise at first so got a sore head for a while!!

1) Azure blob container URL (from the properties in the Storage Explorer)
2) the filename (this is the part I omitted by mistake)
3) Shared Access Signature

So is built like this

```
sURL = destination_folder & "/" & local_file_name & "?" & conn_SAS
```

I don't have the reputation require to comment directly below that answer

Great code though, as soon as I worked out the format of the sURL it worked like a dream

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage Service uses private key authentication. Since VBA runs on the end user's machine you are exposing yourself to a whole slew of risks associated with that key getting into the wild. I would recommend rethinking the whole premise of going directly from VBA to Azure Storage and utilize your own WebAPI to handle storing data to Blob.

This would have the dual benefit of:

1) making it easier to integrate with from VBA and

2) protecting your Azure Storage private key behind a component of your solution that doesn't get deployed to the end user's machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Security isn't really an issue with this application. What I want to avoid is having to install any additional components on the end user's machine. What would I use to create a WebAPI? (I'm a VBA programmer and my knowledge of other languages is limited)

Comment: If you want to build one with VB.NET you could start with a simple ASP.NET Web Application configured. Select WebAPI 2.0. Then you'd simply implement a controller to upload the file to. Check out this basic tutorial [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/uploading-a-file-in-Asp-Net-web-api/). As long as the files you are uploading aren't huge you should be okay.

Comment: If somebody other than you is going to be using the application I'd still be concerned. If your Azure Storage key fell into the wrong hands and you weren't paying attention they could rack up a pretty huge bill for you.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up - I'll take a look. I take your point about the security but in this particular instance it really wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: After a lot of trying to get this working directly from VBA I have found a Microsoft tool that can be called from the command line that works for this application. The tool is called AzCopy and handles both uploads and downloads of files from Azure storage.